# Customize media queries in Bootstrap with Sass

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I want to adjust my screen-sm variable to 800px. Defining this variable before importing sass bootstrap works fine but still when my screen switches to 768px I have a breakpoint and media query with 768px there.

Main scss:

```
$screen-sm: 800px !default;
$screen-sm-min: $screen-sm !default;
$screen-tablet: $screen-sm-min !default;

@import 'sass-bootstrap/lib/bootstrap';
```

This is what I see in dev tools between 768px and 800px:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.container {
    width: 750px;
}
```

Where does Bootstrap take this min-width value from and how can I adjust it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `!default`.  It is not necessary here, as the bootstrap ones are already set to `!default`.  You are overriding the default values.

From SASS documentation:

> You can assign to variables if they aren’t already assigned by adding the !default flag to the end of the value. This means that if the variable has already been assigned to, it won’t be re-assigned, but if it doesn’t have a value yet, it will be given one.

Main.scss should now look like this:

```
$screen-sm: 800px;
$screen-sm-min: $screen-sm;
$screen-tablet: $screen-sm-min;

@import 'sass-bootstrap/lib/bootstrap';
```